# Is there a way to programmatically scroll thought within UWP Microsoft.Toolkit MarkdownTextBlock control?

Tags: c#, uwp, markdown

I'm looking for a way to show some html, csharp, xml or json code within my UWP app in a formatted way. So I thought about using the control `MarkdownTextBlock` from the Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls library to achieve this.

Witch warping the code with the correct Markdown Fence is working great. But now I would like to be able to scroll down the `MarkdownTextBlock` end highlights some specific part of the code.
But the control doesn’t seem to allow this.

I'm I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up, using Monaco Editor.
With is fantastic!

https://github.com/hawkerm/monaco-editor-uwp

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no available build-in APIs for what you want. I'd suggest you put the `MarkdownTextBlock` inside a `ScrollViewer` and try to scroll the `ScrollViewer` instead. Just like what the sample did: [Toolkit SampleApp](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/tree/rel/7.1.2/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.SampleApp)

Comment: That better than nothing a guest